# Indentation only after first paragraph

Tags: xetex, indentation, rules, pandoc, spanish

I am wondering how can I set the indentation of paragraphs only after the first paragraph. By “first“ I mean the first paragraph after any block element (header, list, block quote, formulas, images).

For example, in HTML I can achieve what I want with this CSS rule:

`p+p {
  text-indent:1em;
}`

So I am looking the same result but in LaTeX (I am working on a template for Pandoc).

Currently I have these results that I don't want:

[image]
[image]

---

**Edit**

Examples files: `nube.cliteratu.re/index.php/s/ma5my80zRaoqCeE`. The `es-noindentfirst` doesn't seem to work (line 96 of `template.latex`). I would rather not use `\noindent` cause I am not working with tex files directly but trough Pandoc.

---

**Edit 2**

As suggested by cfr, I put the code of the example:

`template.latex`:

```
\documentclass[$if(fontsize)$$fontsize$,$endif$$if(lang)$$babel-lang$,$endif$$if(papersize)$$papersize$paper,$endif$$for(classoption)$$classoption$$sep$,$endfor$]{$documentclass$}
$if(beamerarticle)$
\usepackage{beamerarticle} % needs to be loaded first
$endif$
$if(fontfamily)$
\usepackage[$for(fontfamilyoptions)$$fontfamilyoptions$$sep$,$endfor$]{$fontfamily$}
$else$
\usepackage{lmodern}
$endif$
$if(linestretch)$
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{$linestretch$}
$endif$
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % provides \textsubscript
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[$if(fontenc)$$fontenc$$else$T1$endif$]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
$if(euro)$
  \usepackage{eurosym}
$endif$
\else % if luatex or xelatex
  \ifxetex
    \usepackage{mathspec}
  \else
    \usepackage{fontspec}
  \fi
  \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase}
$for(fontfamilies)$
  \newfontfamily{$fontfamilies.name$}[$fontfamilies.options$]{$fontfamilies.font$}
$endfor$
$if(euro)$
  \newcommand{\euro}{€}
$endif$
$if(mainfont)$
    \setmainfont[$for(mainfontoptions)$$mainfontoptions$$sep$,$endfor$]{$mainfont$}
$endif$
$if(sansfont)$
    \setsansfont[$for(sansfontoptions)$$sansfontoptions$$sep$,$endfor$]{$sansfont$}
$endif$
$if(monofont)$
    \setmonofont[Mapping=tex-ansi$if(monofontoptions)$,$for(monofontoptions)$$monofontoptions$$sep$,$endfor$$endif$]{$monofont$}
$endif$
$if(mathfont)$
    \setmathfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[$for(mathfontoptions)$$mathfontoptions$$sep$,$endfor$]{$mathfont$}
$endif$
$if(CJKmainfont)$
    \usepackage{xeCJK}
    \setCJKmainfont[$for(CJKoptions)$$CJKoptions$$sep$,$endfor$]{$CJKmainfont$}
$endif$
\fi
% use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
% use microtype if available
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{%
\usepackage[$for(microtypeoptions)$$microtypeoptions$$sep$,$endfor$]{microtype}
\UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url} % url is loaded by hyperref
$if(verbatim-in-note)$
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
$endif$
\usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}
$if(colorlinks)$
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{color} % color is loaded by hyperref
$endif$
\hypersetup{
$if(title-meta)$
            pdftitle={$title-meta$},
$endif$
$if(author-meta)$
            pdfauthor={$author-meta$},
$endif$
$if(keywords)$
            pdfkeywords={$for(keywords)$$keywords$$sep$, $endfor$},
$endif$
$if(colorlinks)$
            colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor=$if(linkcolor)$$linkcolor$$else$Maroon$endif$,
            citecolor=$if(citecolor)$$citecolor$$else$Blue$endif$,
            urlcolor=$if(urlcolor)$$urlcolor$$else$Blue$endif$,
$else$
            pdfborder={0 0 0},
$endif$
            breaklinks=true}
\urlstyle{same}  % don't use monospace font for urls
$if(verbatim-in-note)$
\VerbatimFootnotes % allows verbatim text in footnotes
$endif$
$if(geometry)$
\usepackage[$for(geometry)$$geometry$$sep$,$endfor$]{geometry}
$endif$
$if(lang)$
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[shorthands=off,$for(babel-otherlangs)$$babel-otherlangs$,$endfor$main=$babel-lang$,es-noindentfirst]{babel}
$if(babel-newcommands)$
  $babel-newcommands$
$endif$
\else
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage[$polyglossia-lang.options$]{$polyglossia-lang.name$}
$for(polyglossia-otherlangs)$
  \setotherlanguage[$polyglossia-otherlangs.options$]{$polyglossia-otherlangs.name$}
$endfor$
\fi
$endif$
$if(natbib)$
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{$if(biblio-style)$$biblio-style$$else$plainnat$endif$}
$endif$
$if(biblatex)$
\usepackage[$if(biblio-style)$style=$biblio-style$,$endif$$for(biblatexoptions)$$biblatexoptions$$sep$,$endfor$]{biblatex}
$for(bibliography)$
\addbibresource{$bibliography$}
$endfor$
$endif$
$if(listings)$
\usepackage{listings}
$endif$
$if(lhs)$
\lstnewenvironment{code}{\lstset{language=Haskell,basicstyle=\small\ttfamily}}{}
$endif$
$if(highlighting-macros)$
$highlighting-macros$
$endif$
$if(tables)$
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
% Fix footnotes in tables (requires footnote package)
\IfFileExists{footnote.sty}{\usepackage{footnote}\makesavenoteenv{long table}}{}
$endif$
$if(graphics)$
\usepackage{graphicx,grffile}
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\def\maxheight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>\textheight\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}
\makeatother
% Scale images if necessary, so that they will not overflow the page
% margins by default, and it is still possible to overwrite the defaults
% using explicit options in \includegraphics[width, height, ...]{}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}
$endif$
$if(links-as-notes)$
% Make links footnotes instead of hotlinks:
\renewcommand{\href}[2]{#2\footnote{\url{#1}}}
$endif$
$if(strikeout)$
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
% avoid problems with \sout in headers with hyperref:
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\renewcommand{\sout}{}}
$endif$
$if(indent)$
$else$
\IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
\usepackage{parskip}
}{% else
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
}
$endif$
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
$if(numbersections)$
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{$if(secnumdepth)$$secnumdepth$$else$5$endif$}
$else$
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
$endif$
$if(subparagraph)$
$else$
% Redefines (sub)paragraphs to behave more like sections
\ifx\paragraph\undefined\else
\let\oldparagraph\paragraph
\renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{\oldparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi
\ifx\subparagraph\undefined\else
\let\oldsubparagraph\subparagraph
\renewcommand{\subparagraph}[1]{\oldsubparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi
$endif$
$if(dir)$
\ifxetex
  % load bidi as late as possible as it modifies e.g. graphicx
  $if(latex-dir-rtl)$
  \usepackage[RTLdocument]{bidi}
  $else$
  \usepackage{bidi}
  $endif$
\fi
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \TeXXeTstate=1
  \newcommand{\RL}[1]{\beginR #1\endR}
  \newcommand{\LR}[1]{\beginL #1\endL}
  \newenvironment{RTL}{\beginR}{\endR}
  \newenvironment{LTR}{\beginL}{\endL}
\fi
$endif$

% set default figure placement to htbp
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{htbp}
\makeatother

$for(header-includes)$
$header-includes$
$endfor$

$if(title)$
\title{$title$$if(thanks)$\thanks{$thanks$}$endif$}
$endif$
$if(subtitle)$
\providecommand{\subtitle}[1]{}
\subtitle{$subtitle$}
$endif$
$if(author)$
\author{$for(author)$$author$$sep$ \and $endfor$}
$endif$
$if(institute)$
\providecommand{\institute}[1]{}
\institute{$for(institute)$$institute$$sep$ \and $endfor$}
$endif$
\date{$date$}

% Para la imagen de portada
\usepackage{tikz}

% Modifica la cornisa
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chead{$title$}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}

\begin{document}

% Contenido preliminar
\frontmatter

% Portada
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[inner sep=0] at (current page.center){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{portada.jpg}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\cleardoublepage{}

% Elimina el "Capítulo X"
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}

$if(title)$
\maketitle
$endif$
$if(abstract)$
\begin{abstract}
$abstract$
\end{abstract}
$endif$

% Legal
\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent\textit{Su único hijo}

\noindent Proyecto Gutenberg
\vspace{12pt}

\noindent Autoría

\noindent Leopoldo Alas
\vspace{12pt}

\cleardoublepage{}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}\parbox{0.6\textwidth}{

\vspace{5cm}
\begin{center}
\textsc{Nota}:
\end{center}

\noindent Estos textos han sido tomados de las ediciones originales. 
Se ha respetado la ortografía y la acentuación del original, que difieren de los 
criterios actuales.

}\end{center}

\cleardoublepage{}

$for(include-before)$
$include-before$

$endfor$
$if(toc)$
{
$if(colorlinks)$
\hypersetup{linkcolor=$if(toccolor)$$toccolor$$else$black$endif$}
$endif$
\setcounter{tocdepth}{$toc-depth$}
\tableofcontents
}
$endif$
$if(lot)$
\listoftables
$endif$
$if(lof)$
\listoffigures
$endif$

% Contenido principal
\mainmatter

$body$

$if(natbib)$
$if(bibliography)$
$if(biblio-title)$
$if(book-class)$
\renewcommand\bibname{$biblio-title$}
$else$
\renewcommand\refname{$biblio-title$}
$endif$
$endif$
\bibliography{$for(bibliography)$$bibliography$$sep$,$endfor$}

$endif$
$endif$
$if(biblatex)$
\printbibliography$if(biblio-title)$[title=$biblio-title$]$endif$

$endif$
$for(include-after)$
$include-after$

$endfor$
\end{document}
```

`todo.xhtml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" xml:lang="es" lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Título</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="i">I</h1>
        <p>Emma Valcárcel fue una hija única mimada. A los quince años se enamoró del <em>escribiente</em> de su padre, abogado. El escribiente, llamado Bonifacio Reyes, pertenecía a una honrada familia, <em>distinguida</em> un siglo atrás, pero, hacía dos o tres generaciones, pobre y desgraciada. Bonifacio era un hombre pacífico, suave, moroso, muy sentimental, muy tierno de corazón, maniático de la música y de las historias maravillosas, buen parroquiano del gabinete de lectura de alquiler que había en el pueblo. Era guapo a lo romántico, de estatura regular, rostro <em>ovalado</em> pálido, de hermosa cabellera castaña, fina y con bucles, pie pequeño, buena pierna, esbelto, delgado, y vestía bien, sin afectación, su ropa humilde, no del todo mal cortada. No servía para ninguna clase de trabajo serio y constante; tenía preciosa letra, muy delicada en los perfiles, pero tardaba mucho en llenar una hoja de papel, y su ortografía era extremadamente caprichosa y fantástica; es decir, no era ortografía. Escribía con mayúscula las palabras a que él daba mucha importancia, como eran: amor, caridad, dulzura, perdón, época, otoño, erudito, suave, música, novia, apetito y otras varias. El mismo día en que al padre de Emma, don Diego Valcárcel, de noble linaje y abogado famoso, se le ocurrió despedir al pobre Reyes, porque «<em>en suma</em> no sabía escribir y le ponía en ridículo ante el Juzgado y la Audiencia», se le ocurrió a la niña escapar de casa con su novio. En vano Bonifacio, que se había dejado querer, no quiso dejarse robar; Emma le arrastró a la fuerza, a la fuerza del amor, y la Guardia civil, que empezaba a ser benemérita, sorprendió a los fugitivos en su primera etapa. Emma fue encerrada en un convento y el escribiente desapareció del pueblo, que era una melancólica y aburrida capital de tercer orden, sin que se supiera de él en mucho tiempo. Emma estuvo en su cárcel religiosa algunos años, y volvió al mundo, como si nada hubiera pasado, a la muerte de su padre; rica, arrogante, en poder de un curador, su tío, que era como un mayordomo. Segura ella de su pureza material, todo el empeño de su orgullo era mostrarse inmaculada y obligar a tener fe en su inocencia al mundo entero. Quería casarse o morir; casarse para demostrar la pureza de su honor. Pero los pretendientes aceptables no parecían. La de Valcárcel seguía enamorada, con la imaginación, de su escribiente de los quince años; pero no procuró averiguar su paradero, ni aunque hubiese venido le hubiera entregado su mano, porque esto sería dar la razón a la maledicencia. Quería <em>antes</em> otro marido. Sí, Emma pensaba así, sin darse cuenta de lo que hacía: «<em>Antes</em> otro marido». El <em>después</em> que vagamente esperaba y que entreveía, no era el adulterio, era... tal vez la muerte del primer esposo, una segunda boda a que se creía con derecho. El primer marido pareció a los dos años de vivir libre Emma. Fue un americano nada joven, tosco, enfermizo, taciturno, beato. Se casó con Emma por egoísmo, por tener unas blandas manos que le cuidasen en sus achaques.</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Emma fue una enfermera excelente; se figuraba a sí misma convertida en una monja de la Caridad.</li>
            <li>El marido duró un año.</li>
        </ul>
        <p>Al siguiente, la de Valcárcel dejó el luto, y su tío, el curador-mayordomo, y una multitud de primos, todos Valcárcel, enamorados los más en secreto de Emma, tuvieron por ocupación, en virtud de un <em>ukase</em> de la tirana de la familia, buscar por mar y tierra al fugitivo, al pobre Bonifacio Reyes. Pareció en Méjico, en Puebla. Había ido a buscar fortuna; no la había encontrado. Vivía de administrar mal un periódico, que llamaba chapucero y guanajo a todo el mundo. Vivía triste y pobre, pero callado, tranquilo, resignado con su suerte, mejor, sin pensar en ella.</p>
        <p>Por un corresponsal de un comerciante amigo de los Valcárcel, se pusieron estos en comunicación con Bonifacio. ¿Cómo traerle? ¿De qué modo decente se podía abordar la cuestión? Se le ofreció un destino en un pueblo de la provincia, a tres leguas de la capital, un destino humilde, pero mejor que la administración del periódico mejicano. Bonifacio aceptó, se volvió a su tierra; quiso saber a quién debía tal favor y se le condujo a presencia de un primo de Emma, rival algún día de Reyes. A la semana siguiente Emma y Bonifacio se vieron, y a los tres meses se casaron. A los ocho días la de Valcárcel comprendió que no era aquel el Bonifacio que ella había soñado. Era, aunque muy pacífico, más molesto que el curador-mayordomo, y menos poético que el primo Sebastián, que la había amado sin esperanza desde los veinte años hasta la mayor edad.</p>
        <img src="sample.png" />
        <p>A los dos meses de matrimonio Emma sintió que en ella se despertaba un intenso, poderosísimo cariño a todos los de su raza, vivos y muertos; se rodeó de parientes, hizo restaurar, por un dineral, multitud de cuadros viejos, retratos de sus antepasados; y, sin decirlo a nadie, se enamoró, a su vez, en secreto y también sin esperanza, del insigne D. Antonio Diego Valcárcel Merás, fundador de la casa de Valcárcel, famoso guerrero que hizo y deshizo en la guerra de las Alpujarras. Armado de punta en blanco, avellanado y cejijunto, de mirada penetrante, y brillando como un sol, gracias al barniz reciente, el misterioso personaje del lienzo se ofrecía a los ojos soñadores de Emma como el tipo ideal de grandezas muertas, irreemplazables. Estar enamorada de un su abuelo, que era el símbolo de toda la vida caballeresca que ella se figuraba a su modo, era digna pasión de una mujer que ponía todos sus conatos en distinguirse de las demás. Este afán de separarse de la corriente, de romper toda regla, de desafiar murmuraciones y vencer imposibles y provocar escándalos, no era en ella alarde frío, pedantesca vanidad de mujer extraviada por lecturas disparatadas; era espontánea perversión del espíritu, prurito de enferma. Mucho perdió el primo Sebastián con aquella restauración de la iconoteca familiar. Si Emma había estado a tres dedos del abismo, que no se sabe, su enamoramiento secreto y puramente ideal la libró de todo peligro positivo; entre Sebastián y su prima se había atravesado un pedazo de lienzo viejo. Una tarde, casi a oscuras, paseaban juntos por el salón de los retratos, y cuando Sebastián preparaba una frase que en pocas palabras explicase los grandes méritos que había adquirido amando tantos años sin decir palabra ni esperar cosa de provecho, Emma se le puso delante, le mandó encender una luz y acercarla al retrato del ilustre abuelo.—Sí, os parecéis algo—dijo ella—; pero se ve claramente que nuestra raza ha degenerado. Era él mucho más guapo y más robusto que tú. Ahora los Valcárcel sois todos de alfeñique; si a ti te cargaran con esa armadura, estarías gracioso.</p>
        <p>Sebastián continuó amando en secreto y sin esperanza. El guerrero de las Alpujarras siguió velando por el honor de su raza.</p>
        <p>Bonifacio no sospechaba nada ni del primo ni del abuelo. En cuanto su mujer dio por terminada la luna de miel, que fue bien pronto, como se encontrase él demasiado libre de ocupaciones, porque el tío mayordomo seguía corriendo con todo por expreso mandato de Emma, se dio a buscar un <em>ser a quien amar</em>, <em>algo que le llenase la vida</em>. Es de notar que Bonifacio, hombre sencillo en el lenguaje y en el trato, frío en apariencia, oscuro y prosaico en gestos, acciones y palabras, a pesar de su belleza plástica, <em>por dentro</em>, como él se decía, era un soñador, un soñador soñoliento, y hablándose a sí mismo, usaba un estilo elevado y sentimental de que ni él se daba cuenta. Buscando, pues, algo que le llenara la vida, encontró una flauta. Era una flauta de ébano con llaves de plata, que pareció entre los papeles de su suegro. El abogado del ilustre Colegio, a sus solas, era romántico también, aunque algo viejo, y tocaba la flauta con mucho sentimiento, pero jamás en público. Emma, después de pensarlo, no tuvo inconveniente en que la flauta de su padre pasara a manos de su marido. El cual, después de untarla bien con aceite, y dejarla, merced a ciertas composturas, como nueva, se consagró a la música, su afición favorita, en cuerpo y alma. Se reconoció aptitudes algo más que medianas, una regular embocadura y mucho sentimiento, sobre todo. El timbre dulzón, <em>nasal</em> podría decirse, monótono y manso del melancólico instrumento, que olía a aceite de almendras como la cabeza del músico, estaba en armonía con el carácter de Bonifacio Reyes; hasta la inclinación de cabeza a que le obligaba el tañer, inclinación que Reyes exageraba, contribuía a darle cierto parecido con un bienaventurado. Reyes, tocando la flauta, recordaba un santo músico de un pintor pre-rafaelista. Sobre el agujero negro, entre el bigote de seda de un castaño claro, se veía de vez en cuando la punta de la lengua, limpia y sana; los ojos, azules claros, grandes y dulces, buscaban, como los de un místico, lo más alto de su órbita; pero no por esto miraban al cielo, sino a la pared de enfrente, porque Reyes tenía la cabeza gacha como si fuera a embestir. Solía marcar el compás con la punta de un pie, azotando el suelo, y en los pasajes de mucha expresión, con suaves ondulaciones de todo el cuerpo, tomando por quicio la cintura. En los <em>allegros</em> se sacudía con fuerza y animación, extraña en hombre al parecer tan apático; los ojos, antes sin vida y atentos nada más a la música, como si fueran parte integrante de la flauta o dependiesen de ella por oculto resorte, cobraban ánimo, y tomaban calor y brillo, y mostraban apuros indecibles, como los de un animal inteligente que pide socorro. Bonifacio, en tales trances, parecía un náufrago ahogándose y que en vano busca una tabla de salvación; la tirantez de los músculos del rostro, el rojo que encendía las mejillas y aquel afán de la mirada, creía Reyes que expresarían la intensidad de sus impresiones, su grandísimo amor a la melodía; pero más parecían signos de una irremediable asfixia; hacían pensar en la apoplejía, en cualquier terrible crisis fisiológica, pero no en el hermoso corazón del melómano, sencillo como una paloma.</p>
        <p>Por no molestar a nadie, ni gastar dinero de su mujer, puesto que propio no lo tenía, en comprar papeles de música, pedía prestadas las polkas y las partituras enteras de ópera italiana que eran su encanto, y él mismo copiaba todos aquellos <em>torrentes de armonía y melodía</em>, representados por los amados signos del pentagrama. Emma no le pedía cuenta de estas aficiones ni del tiempo que le ocupaban, que era la mayor parte del día. Sólo le exigía estar siempre vestido, y bien vestido, a las horas señaladas para salir a paseo o a visitas. Su Bonifacio no era más que una figura de adorno para ella; por dentro no tenía nada, era un alma de cántaro; pero la figura se podía presentar y dar con ella envidia a muchas señoronas del pueblo. Lucía a su marido, a quien compraba buena ropa, que él vestía bien, y se reservaba el derecho de tenerle por <em>un alma de Dios</em>. Él parecía, en los primeros tiempos, contento con su suerte. No entraba ni salía en los negocios de la casa; no gastaba más que un pobre estudiante en el regalo de su persona, pues aquello de la ropa lujosa no era en rigor gasto propio, sino de la vanidad de su mujer; a él le agradaba parecer bien, pero hubiera prescindido de este lujo indumentario sin un solo suspiro; además, creía ocioso y gasto inútil aquello de encargar los pantalones y las levitas a Madrid, exceso de <em>dandysmo</em>, entonces inaudito en el pueblo. Conocía él un sastre modesto, flautista también, que por poco dinero era capaz de cortar no peor que los empecatados <em>artistas</em> de la corte. Esto lo pensaba, pero no lo decía. Se dejaba vestir. Su resolución era pesar lo menos posible sobre la casa de los Valcárcel, y callar a todo.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Command used for compile the PDF with Pandoc:

```
pandoc todo.xhtml --latex-engine=xelatex --template=template.latex --toc --toc-depth=1 -V lang:es -V documentclass:book -V papersize:a5 -V classoption:oneside -V geometry:margin=1in -V indent:true -V title:"Su único hijo" -V author:"Leopoldo Alas" -o todo.pdf
```

Comment: [Another image of I want to correct (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhClP.jpg).

Comment: what document class are you using.  even more helpful would be a small compilable example that illustrates the present situation in a way that someone here can modify the code to produce the result you are looking for.

Comment: no indentation after a section heading is usually the default, you will not get indentation after a list if it is not a new paragraph (that is, there is no blank line before or after the list)

Comment: The default in Spanish is indent always (but you can use the option  `es-noindentfirst` in babel package).

Comment: For special cases (other that first paragraphs and after lists)  you can also avoid manually  the indentation with `\noindent`.

Comment: [Click here for the examples files](http://nube.cliteratu.re/index.php/s/ma5my80zRaoqCeE). The `es-noindentfirst` doesn't seem to work (line 96 of `template.latex`). I would rather not use `\noindent` cause I am not working with tex files directly but trough Pandoc.

Comment: Please add code here in the form of a minimal document we can compile. Your question should remain useful for future users searching for answers. This means it can't depend on the content of external links, as these may well change.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems at work:

The indentation after the chapter is normal for Spanish as noted by @Fran. You can inhibit that by using the option `es-noindentfirst` for `babel`. But that is only used together with `(pdf)latex`. When `xelatex` is used, `babel` is replaced by `polyglossia` (lines 95-106 in `template.latex`). I do not know if  `polyglossia` offers a similar option to `es-noindentfirst`.

For lists and graphics `pandoc` produces LaTeX code like this:

```
Se casó con Emma por egoísmo, por tener
unas blandas manos que le cuidasen en sus achaques.

\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  Emma fue una enfermera excelente; se figuraba a sí misma convertida en
  una monja de la Caridad.
\item
  El marido duró un año.
\end{itemize}

Al siguiente, la de Valcárcel dejó el luto, y su tío, el
curador-mayordomo, y una multitud de primos, todos Valcárcel, enamorados
```

Here LaTeX has no other possibility as to assume you want a new (indented) paragraph to start. You can either bring the list and the paragraph together by removing or commenting the empty line. Or you can add `\noindent` before the new paragraph. I do not know if this can be automatized via `pandoc`.

Comment: It seems I will have to add more code to my script so instead of going directly to a PDF, convert to LaTeX, made modifications to the documents and then to PDF :/